# Multi-language storesetup rewrite issue

Tags: multistore, ce-1.9.1.0, url-rewrite

Currently we have a store setup on a single domain with 2 languages. Where the URL's look like this:

Dutch: http://www.example.com/nederlandse_product_url
English: http://www.example.com/english_product_url

When you're in the dutch storeview on the frontend and types in the dutch URL in the address bar, there's no problem. The same for English.

But if you're on the English view and you type in the Dutch URL in the address bar, you get a 404 error.

Is there anyway to check from which storeview the url is and direct the visitor to the correct storeview, without changing the url structure?

Comment: why do you need this? you dont type urls, you just click the link in menu, which is from 100% correct store view..

Comment: @MagenX: This is needed by a lot of store owners, since the URLs for all store views are indexed by search engines.

Comment: @MagenX, it's what jhoelzl says: Google index the pages with a 404 error.  Besides of that, when a store owner gives an direct link to the customer and storeview isn't correct the customer gets a 404 error.

Comment: could you please post just /url to en and dk products. and are these products the same? available in both shops

Comment: @MartijnBastiaansen: I had the same issue and wrote a small Magento module for this problem which redirects the user to the correct store view (or best matching store view if the Request-URL is the same for multiple store views).  It uses the event `controller_front_init_routers`.

Comment: @jhoelzl, Do you have some more information about your module or a link or something to it?

Comment: @MartijnBastiaansen, currently it is only developed for my Magento system. But i will try to make the source code available on github and send you the link.

Comment: @MartijnBastiaansen, try [this module](https://github.com/jhoelzl/JH_Storeredirect), but test your behaviour after installation, maybe some unwanted redirections are performed.

Comment: @jhoelz, Looks like it's working thanks. Will test it further with the store owners.

Comment: we still dont know if the product is available in other store view...

Comment: @MagenX: This might be the case (it is so in my shop), but is not the point of that issue. The issue is simply that you can not access an URL from another Magento store view that is not your current store view. You always get redirected to a 404 page of the current store view.

Comment: @MagenX, the products are avaible in the other store view. But that isn't the issue as Jhoelzl pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

ive just tested `dk/en` shop for this issue, and the only difference i found is `/store_code/`  in url is present and products have the same url for both views.

```
shop.com/store_dk/product.html
shop.com/store_en/product.html
```

either you have different url for product in every store or store code is not included?

Comment: As you can see in the original question, there isn't a store code configured in the url as this was a requirement for the shop. That's why there s a problem with the url rewriting and the extension from Jhoelzl is fixing the issue.

Comment: Yes, the issue only arises if you deactivated storecode for your urls. Mostly, you do not want to have the storecode in the urls.

Comment: SO how do you get into specific store then ? we need to find the bug.

Comment: Example:
I have a website with 1 store and 2 store views (german and english).  My category in english is mydomain.com/batteries.html. When i am in this english storeview and type in the browser mydomain.com/akkus.html (same category but german store view) i get an 404 error. I have to first switch to the german store view, than the URL mydomain.com/akkus.html works.

Comment: When you append the value `___store` to the request URL, such as mydomain.com/akkus.html?___store=german_storeview_code, then the correct store view is choosen without having to switch the storeview manually. That's what my module does.